# Find the instantaneous change of rate using only limits

Tags: limits

I was asked to find the area of each new shaded square and the total area of the shaded squares altogether following the pattern shown below:

[image]

I completed the table below (the second row being individual shaded area for each new square and the third row being the total shaded area for each figure), and then was asked to find an algebraic expression that allowed me to find the total shaded area for any given figure.

[image]

I got the following:

$$f(n)= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \left(-2+2^n\right) $$ 
Then I was asked to find the instantaneous change of rate when $n=11$

I got this & can't seem to know what to do next:

$$ \lim_{x\to a} {2^\left(1-a-x\right)\left(2^a-2^x\right) \over (a-x)} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total shaded area is given by

$$
f(n)=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}
$$

(You see that total shaded area is area of whole square (which is 1) $-$ unshaded rectangle, which at step $n$ has area $1/2^{n-1}$)

Then

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(11+h)-f(11)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2^{10}} - \frac{1}{2^{10+h}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1 - 2^{-h}}{2^{10}h}=2^{-10}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1 - \exp(-h\log 2)}{h}=2^{-10}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1 - (1-h \log 2 + O(h^2))}{h}=2^{-10}\lim_{h\to 0}[\log 2 +O(h)]=2^{-10}\log 2
$$

Comment: Don't really understand what you did from step 2 to 3 when solving the limit nor what does O (h) mean.

Comment: Do you know that $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$?

Comment: No. Didn't know that.

Comment: I used the fact that $2^{-h}=e^{\log 2^{-h}}=e^{-h\log2}$ and used above expansion of $e$ to get $2^{-h}=1-h\log2+(h^2(\log 2)^2)/2 +\cdots$ and you see that for $k\ge 2$ we have $h^k/h=h^{k-1} \to 0$ as $h\to 0$, so we can ignore $h^k$ for $k\ge 2$ (which I represented by $O(h^2)/h=O(h)$. Basically $O(h)$ means something that goes to $0$ when $h\to 0$. If this doesn't make any sense to you I highly suspect this question was meant to be solve-able for you.

Comment: That certainly is quite advanced for what we're being taught. I'm wondering if there isn't any other way because I'm not sure I'd be able to explain how I figured out the answer.

Comment: I'm actually suspecting if the question is meant to compute $f(12)-f(11)/(12-11)=f(12)-f(11)$. (ie just gradient from $(11,f(11)) $ to $(12,f(12))$. Otherwise, I don't think there's any more elementary method to show the limit. If there was one I think it would be very trick-involving... Have you ever learnt about differentiation of functions of the form $f(x)=a^x$?

Comment: I thought about that too but since it said "instantaneous change of rate" I just used the same formula you used because that's what the book said, the one you're suggesting isn't for the instantaneous change of rate. And not really, I'd assume it involves using natural logarithm.

Comment: Have you actually seen the limit: $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48204/discussion-between-nicholas-j-and-user160738).